# HTML - Multiple Forms on One Page - Sends CSV list in POST Method

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, asp-classic

I have multiple forms on one HTML page. The forms use an image as the submit button. The image can change with a mouseover event. Each form displays its base (initial) image based on the value of a variable. When the user clicks an image (represents their selection), it will be in 1 of the 5 forms on the page. All 5 forms have some fields that are names the same, such as their customer ID. When the form is submitted to the action page, I see the data for each form element as a CSV list of the options available in all 5 forms instead of just the one that was clicked on.

The Form Code:

```
ELSE
'   THIS AREA IS FOR MEMBERS WHO DO HAVE A SUBSCRIPTION - THEY CAN SEE ALL THE OTHER PACKAGES AND SELECT THE ONE THAT THEY WANT - EITHER AN UPGRADE OR A DOWNGRADE
%>
<span class="mainHeadBlack">Your current Package is selected below. Do You need more benefits?</span><br />
<%
IF CINT(CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID) = CINT(Bronze_Subscription_ID) THEN 
%>
<form action="TFI_member_account_page_upgrade_membership.asp" method="post" id="frm6" name="frm6">
<input type="hidden" id="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" name="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" value="<%=CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_BRONZE" name="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_BRONZE" value="<%=Bronze_Subscription_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="PERSON_ID" name="PERSON_ID" value="<%=SESSION("PERSON_ID")%>">
<input type="hidden" id="CIM_PROFILE_ID" name="CIM_PROFILE_ID" value="<%=CIM_PROFILE_ID%>">
<input type="image" src="images/btns_BronzePackageChecked.png" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='images/btns_BronzePackageUnChecked.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='images/btns_BronzePackageChecked.png'" id="Bronze Package Free Membership" alt="Bronze Package Free Membership"/>
<% else %>
<form action="TFI_member_account_page_upgrade_membership.asp" method="post" id="frm7" name="frm7">
<input type="hidden" id="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" name="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" value="<%=CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" name="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" value="<%=Bronze_Subscription_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="PERSON_ID" name="PERSON_ID" value="<%=SESSION("PERSON_ID")%>">
<input type="hidden" id="CIM_PROFILE_ID" name="CIM_PROFILE_ID" value="<%=CIM_PROFILE_ID%>">
<input type="image" src="images/btns_BronzePackageUnChecked.png" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='images/btns_BronzePackageChecked.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='images/btns_BronzePackageUnChecked.png'" id="Bronze Package Free Membership" alt="Bronze Package Free Membership"/>
<% 
end if 

IF CINT(CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID) = CINT(Silver_Subscription_ID) THEN 
%>
<form action="TFI_member_account_page_upgrade_membership" method="post" id="frm8" name="frm8">
<input type="hidden" id="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" name="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" value="<%=CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_SILVER" name="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_SILVER" value="<%=Silver_Subscription_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="PERSON_ID" name="PERSON_ID" value="<%=SESSION("PERSON_ID")%>">
<input type="hidden" id="CIM_PROFILE_ID" name="CIM_PROFILE_ID" value="<%=CIM_PROFILE_ID%>">
<input type="image" src="images/btns_SilverPackageUpgrdChecked.png" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='images/btns_SilverPackageUpgrdUnChecked.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='images/btns_SilverPackageUpgrdChecked.png'" id="Silver Free Trial Package" alt="Silver Free Trial Package"/>
<% else %>
<form action="TFI_member_account_page_upgrade_membership" method="post" id="frm9" name="frm9">
<input type="hidden" id="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" name="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" value="<%=CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_SILVER" name="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_SILVER" value="<%=Silver_Subscription_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="PERSON_ID" name="PERSON_ID" value="<%=SESSION("PERSON_ID")%>">
<input type="hidden" id="CIM_PROFILE_ID" name="CIM_PROFILE_ID" value="<%=CIM_PROFILE_ID%>">
<input type="image" src="images/btns_SilverPackageUpgrdUnChecked.png" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='images/btns_SilverPackageUpgrdChecked.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='images/btns_SilverPackageUpgrdUnChecked.png'" id="Silver Free Trial Package" alt="Silver Free Trial Package"/>
<% 
end if 

IF CINT(CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID) = CINT(Gold_Subscription_ID) THEN 
%>
<form action="TFI_member_account_page_upgrade_membership.asp" method="post" id="frm10" name="frm10">
<input type="hidden" id="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" name="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" value="<%=CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_GOLD" name="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_GOLD" value="<%=Gold_Subscription_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="PERSON_ID" name="PERSON_ID" value="<%=SESSION("PERSON_ID")%>">
<input type="hidden" id="CIM_PROFILE_ID" name="CIM_PROFILE_ID" value="<%=CIM_PROFILE_ID%>">
<input type="image" src="images/btns_GoldPackagechecked.png" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='images/btns_GoldPackageUnChecked.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='images/btns_GoldPackagechecked.png'" id="Gold Membership Package" alt="Gold Membership Package"/>
<% else %>
<form action="TFI_member_account_page_upgrade_membership.asp" method="post" id="frm11" name="frm11">
<input type="hidden" id="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" name="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" value="<%=CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_GOLD" name="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_GOLD" value="<%=Gold_Subscription_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="PERSON_ID" name="PERSON_ID" value="<%=SESSION("PERSON_ID")%>">
<input type="hidden" id="CIM_PROFILE_ID" name="CIM_PROFILE_ID" value="<%=CIM_PROFILE_ID%>">
<input type="image" src="images/btns_GoldPackageUnchecked.png" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='images/btns_GoldPackageChecked.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='images/btns_GoldPackageUnchecked.png'" id="Gold Membership Package" alt="Gold Membership Package"/>
<% 
end if 

IF CINT(CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID) = CINT(Platinum_Subscription_ID) THEN 
%>
<form action="TFI_member_account_page_upgrade_membership.asp" method="post" id="frm12" name="frm12">
<input type="hidden" id="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" name="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" value="<%=CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_PLATINUM" name="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_PLATINUM"  value="<%=Platinum_Subscription_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="PERSON_ID" name="PERSON_ID" value="<%=SESSION("PERSON_ID")%>">
<input type="hidden" id="CIM_PROFILE_ID" name="CIM_PROFILE_ID" value="<%=CIM_PROFILE_ID%>">
<input type="image" src="images/btns_PlatinumPackagechecked.png" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='images/btns_PlatinumPackageUnChecked.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='images/btns_PlatinumPackagechecked.png'" id="Platinum Membership Package" alt="Platinum Membership Package"/>
<% else %>
<form action="TFI_member_account_page_upgrade_membership.asp" method="post" id="frm13" name="frm13">
<input type="hidden" id="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" name="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" value="<%=CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_PLATINUM" name="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_PLATINUM"  value="<%=Platinum_Subscription_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="PERSON_ID" name="PERSON_ID" value="<%=SESSION("PERSON_ID")%>">
<input type="hidden" id="CIM_PROFILE_ID" name="CIM_PROFILE_ID" value="<%=CIM_PROFILE_ID%>">
<input type="image" src="images/btns_PlatinumPackageUnchecked.png" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='images/btns_PlatinumPackageChecked.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='images/btns_PlatinumPackageUnchecked.png'" id="Platinum Membership Package" alt="Platinum Membership Package"/>
<% 
end if 
IF CINT(CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID) = CINT(VIP_Subscription_ID) THEN 
%>
<form action="TFI_member_account_page_upgrade_membership.asp" method="post" id="frm14" name="frm14">
<input type="hidden" id="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" name="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" value="<%=CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_VIP" name="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_VIP" value="<%=VIP_Subscription_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="PERSON_ID" name="PERSON_ID" value="<%=SESSION("PERSON_ID")%>">
<input type="hidden" id="CIM_PROFILE_ID" name="CIM_PROFILE_ID" value="<%=CIM_PROFILE_ID%>">
<input type="image" src="images/btns_VipPackageChecked.png" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='images/btns_VipPackageUnChecked.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='images/btns_VipPackageChecked.png'" id="V.I.P. Membership Package" alt="V.I.P. Membership Package"/>
<% else %>
<form action="TFI_member_account_page_upgrade_membership.asp" method="post" id="frm15" name="frm15">
<input type="hidden" id="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" name="CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" value="<%=CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_VIP" name="DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_VIP" value="<%=VIP_Subscription_ID%>">
<input type="hidden" id="PERSON_ID" name="PERSON_ID" value="<%=SESSION("PERSON_ID")%>">
<input type="hidden" id="CIM_PROFILE_ID" name="CIM_PROFILE_ID" value="<%=CIM_PROFILE_ID%>">
<input type="image" src="images/btns_VipPackageUnChecked.png" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='images/btns_VipPackageChecked.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='images/btns_VipPackageUnChecked.png'" id="V.I.P. Membership Package" alt="V.I.P. Membership Package"/>
<% 
    end if
```

The results are returned like this:

```
CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID HAS A VALUE OF: 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_BRONZE HAS A VALUE OF: 5
DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_SILVER HAS A VALUE OF: 4
DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_GOLD HAS A VALUE OF: 3
DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_PLATINUM HAS A VALUE OF: 2
DESIRED_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_VIP HAS A VALUE OF: 1
PERSON_ID HAS A VALUE OF: 100320, 100320, 100320, 100320, 100320
CIM_PROFILE_ID HAS A VALUE OF: 24721500, 24721500, 24721500, 24721500, 24721500
REQUEST.Form(CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID) 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
REQUEST.Form(CIM_PROFILE_ID) 24721500, 24721500, 24721500, 24721500, 24721500
```

From this format I can't tell which form was submitted as all the data is returned to the action page even though only one of the submit images was clicked.

I've tried to make the desired subscription ID a unique value in hopes that only one of them would be returned. No joy. Looking for a strategy that will allow me to identify which of the desired packages (form) the user clicked on. Since each form is named differently - Perhaps an AJAX solution using the submit button with an onclick event and send only the fields of that form through the AJAX functions and record the data that way?

Comment: It helps if you close each of the forms - otherwise the page interprets all the fields as all the same form.

Answer =  add this tag </form>  after each form  tag and its elements. duh..

Comment: Post your answer so others can benefit. see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've realized by now, the problem was that you didn't close your form tags. Thus, you didn't actually have a page with multiple forms on it. Instead, you had a form (the first one) with multiple versions of each field, and the browser did what it always does with multiple fields of the same name: it returned a comma-separated list of values.